# Why is my ngrx Effect transforming a string parameter into an array?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

#### Action

I have the following action:

```
export const searchTM = createAction(
    IocActionTypes.SearchTM,
    props<{tm: string}>()
);
```

#### Component

I have the following code in one of my components:

```
this.store.dispatch(searchTM(value));
```

where `value` is the string `03F`

#### Effects

In my ngrx Effects file I have the following:

```
searchTM$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(iocActions.searchTM),
    mergeMap(val => this.iocService.getGridRowByTM(val.tm)
      .pipe(
        map(rowdataraw => iocActions.searchTMFound({rowdataraw})),
        catchError(() => {
            return EMPTY;
        })
      )
      )
    )
  );
```

but when I set a debug point on the mergeMap `val` variable, I see it come up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing the parameter in the wrong format.

I was using:

```
this.store.dispatch(searchTM(value));
```

where I should have been using:

```
this.store.dispatch(searchTM({tm: value}));
```

Comment: Thanks I  had the same problem